# Why should I use customErrors mode "Off" in web config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

My web app is working fine in my local machine. But at the server, it is giving the titled error. In web config, customErrors mode supposed to be off.

**Question**:

what is the purpose of using customErrors mode? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means ,it's someting wrong with your aplication in server. But it's can't be saw,because you  do not config  customers can see the real errors.It's not safety.

If you want to know what happened in your server. You can  boswer your web site with :localhost in your server maching.

Or you can add a config   `<customErrors  mode="Off" />` in your web.config  file  inside `<system.web>` node.

Comment: Hi in your answer "But it's can't be saw,because you do not config customer can see the real error.It's not safety" is not clear. Can you/anyone clarify a bit? I put customErrors portion inside <system.web> node, but still error.

Comment: Sory for my pool English.And <customErrors  mode="Off" /> means the local user and remote user can see the actually errors.But default is only local user can see it. And it's still error  but the error page does changed?

Comment: Calm down~Let's  try  access to remote desktop.And boswer your aplication url whit local address like:  localhost/defaul.aspx.And see has sometion useful error info

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It happened due to wrong connection string, after correcting it and now it's working fine. Oh great relief! Thanks.